# Check if value exists in a column based on multiple conditions (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following dataset of clients that have driven in a car, every row indicates a single trip.

| Row | Client | Year&weeknum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 202301 |
| 2 | 1 | 202301 |
| 3 | 3 | 202301 |
| 4 | 1 | 202302 |
| 5 | 2 | 202302 |
| 6 | 1 | 202303 |
| 7 | 2 | 202303 |
| 8 | 1 | 202304 |
| 9 | 2 | 202304 |
| 10 | 1 | 202305 |
| 11 | 2 | 202305 |
| 12+ | ... | ... |

I would like to create an additional column that calculates the number of clients that have driven in the past 4 weeks. For example in this dataset that number will on row 8 & 9 will be 1, since only client 1 has driven in week 202304 and the 3 weeks before 202304.

For rows 10 & 11 this number will be 2, since both clients 1 and 2 have driven in week 203505 and the three weeks before 203505.

The dataset contains 500+ rows with dates of the past 12 months or so.

I have tried IF / MATCH / FREQUENCY formula's and combinations but couldn't get to the right answer. Would be great if someone knows how to to this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have data over the past 12 months or so, does this mean there are several years involved?

Comment: Yes 2022 and 2023 years are involved, that is why I have created the year&weeknum column

Comment: Wait, so if you have created that column, that means you know the actual dates? I think that would be a better starting point.

Comment: Yes, date and time like this: 2022-09-09 20:48:03

Comment: So can you confirm that this column actually is numeric? And can you please include this data in your sample? Like I said, it might be a better starting point then your calculated column

Comment: Sample is just an example, not the real dataset. Would a screenshot work of the real data set?

The column is in general format at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment section, if you know the dates then save yourself from extra hassle and use this valuable data:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(x,C2:C12-WEEKDAY(C2:C12,2)+1,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,LET(z,UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B12,x=y)),SUM(--MAP(z,LAMBDA(u,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(x,(B2:B12=u)*(x>=(y-21))*(x<=y))))=4)))))))
```

The idea here was to calculate all starting weekdays for all days (variable 'x') and use this in our further calculation. The shortest version I can give is that I calculated the amount of unique clients that have had a ride per row based on the 'x' variable minus 21 days. This should allow for skipping over year-end.

Comment: JvdV i just see your solution and i will vote for her.
i ve try converting everything in excel 2021 were there is no lambda or map but i get stuck.
If you have the time can you please convert your solution to excel 2021?
Thank you